# How to undo autoremove

Tags: 20.04, sudo

I am a beginner at using Ubuntu, I don't know the commands, I typed sudo apt autoremove to remove python.
My desktop is gone, it is showing black screen.
What should I do next, could please someone tell me?

Thanks

Comment: Python is part of the Ubuntu OS. If you remove it the system will not work. Start fresh and install again. This time don't remove python.

Comment: The files in `/var/log/apt/ ` contain a history of all package installations and removals  However, you MUST NOT "remove python". Many system tools won't work without python. I agree with @user68186 Reinstall, and don't do that. Python 3 is available: `python3  --version`

Comment: @kanehekili In the "more than 100", is there any hint as to why? What line of thinking led to "Uninstall Python, that'll fix it"? Does it come from Windows(tm)? Hacker recipes?

Comment: No, you are right and I've deleted that comment. (I've just seen too many of these questions). Thanks for for your hint.

Comment: What did you do before that, to make python autoremovable? That's the real question and whatever it was, don't do that again.

Comment: @waltinator it seems to me that many new users are blindly following tutorials or youtube videos that tell them to install a different version of python and remove the original one. To what end? No clue.

Answer (score 0):

You destroyed your desktop. Many parts of the desktop rely on the default python version. Removing python unavoidably causes the removal of the desktop.

The easiest approach, however, is to **reinstall the operating system using a live USB or DVD**.

Altrernatively, if you manage to log in to a text console or to a recovery prompt with network access, you could reinstall the entire desktop with the command `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`. However, option 1 is by far easiest for beginning users.